How Do I Stick A Text field on the bottom of App
I am trying to fix a text field at the bottom of the app page. It shouldn't scroll.
It is similar to what we have on Twitter

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [
        //add your scrollable stuff inside Expanded
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 50,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text('ListItem $index');
              },
            ),
          ),
          const Divider(height: 0.1),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 8),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Post Your Reply",
                  enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}


